# Smoothness of marginal distribution of a diffusion in the initial condition

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Let $\{p_t\}_{t \ge 0}$ be a one-dimensional diffusion process (on [0,1] ) with drift $\mu(p) = C_1(1-p)-C_2p+p(1-p)s(p),$ where $s$ is a Lipschitz function and $C_1,C_2 \in (0,1)$, and diffusion $\sigma(p)=\sqrt{p(1-p)}$.

Is there any way to tell whether $\mathbb{P}[p_t \ge \epsilon|p_0=p]=\mathbb{P}_p[p_t \ge \epsilon]$ is (for a fixed $\epsilon \in (0,1)$ and $t \ge 0$) a smooth function of $p$ on $(0,1)$, or at least on $(0,b)$ for some $b \in (0,1)$? I see that it is definitely not continuous at $0$, since there it is nothing but an indicator function of being above $\epsilon$, but this fortunately is not a problem.

Googling seems to find some articles that appear to give criteria for continuity, but I have not been able to find anything about smoothness in this case, even though it seems like something that should be pretty well researched...any ideas or links to relevant articles would be very welcome.